# <input type="text" lose focus after 1'st key press in chrome

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm having a textbox which is "observed" by a jquery for several actions, all code being a part of a "search-as-you-type" form.
Well, everything works flawlessly on Mozilla but in Chrome, the textbox is losing focus after 1'st hit, so I have to click again in textbox to continue search. Any clue ? My experience is leading me to a bug

```
<div class="search-container">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="searchb" >
</div>

<script>    
$('input[name="searchb"]').on('input propertychange 
paste',function(){

if ($(this).val().length > 2){
    document.cookie = "psearch="+this.value+";"+"path=/";
    window.open("main.php?psearch="+this.value, "iframe_a");
    }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Why are you doing `window.open()`?

Comment: does this happen only when `if ($(this).val().length > 2)` condition is true?

Comment: This code works for me in both Chrome and Firefox. If you comment out just this event listener, does the input still lose focus after 1 keystroke?

Comment: @Patrick Q, because I have to post the results somewhere, I see no other way to do that other than opening a page in a frame, I could try with div refresh, still can't figure out the best practice, nevertheless I might end up hitting the same problem.

Comment: @kingunits Do some research on ajax.  That's what you want here.

Comment: @newUserName02 if I strip out the event listener the input box behave as a regular text box. Forgot to mention that  browsers runs on macOS Mojave 10.14.4, even safari works fine with event listener. Must be something chromish here.

Comment: @ekcrisp -no , as I said it lose focus after 1'st keystroke, so the event listener is bothering it, not the alleged window.open()

Comment: I tried Chrome and on Linux and Windows, same stupid behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Your search input is losing focus because the new opened window will gain focus.

Moreover, with your current code, a new window is opened each time an input with a length more than two characters is detected.

There are many solutions, here are two of them. I didn't put them into code snippets because they will not work correctly.

---

## AJAX

You can get the generated HTML of `main.php` thanks to an AJAX request:

**HTML**

```html
<div class="search-container">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="searchb" >
</div>

<div id="searchb-result"></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('input[name="searchb"]').on('input propertychange paste', function() {
    // Empties the result container.
    $('#searchb-result').empty();

    if ($(this).val().length > 2) {
        document.cookie = `psearch=${this.value};path=/`;

        // Gets the HTML by AJAX and adds it to the result container.
        $.get('main.php', `psearch=${this.value}`, (html) => {
            $('#searchb-result').html(html);
        });
    }
});
```

---

## `<iframe>`

You can load your URL in a `<iframe>` tag.

**HTML**

```html
<div class="search-container">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="searchb" >
</div>

<iframe style="display:none;"></iframe>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('input[name="searchb"]').on('input propertychange paste', function() {
    // Hides the <iframe> by default.
    $('iframe').hide();

    if ($(this).val().length > 2) {
        document.cookie = `psearch=${this.value};path=/`;

        // Updates the <iframe> source when an input is detected.
        $('iframe')
            .attr('src', `main.php?psearch=${this.value}`)
            .show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote the entire section without jquery , clean and a with bit of 4'th grade approach, but it works. The lost focus was the problem.

```
<div class="search-container">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="searchb" id="search" autofocus="autofocus">
</div>

<script>
window.name = 'parent';

search.onchange = search.oninput = search.onpaste = function() {
        var sv = search.value;
    if (sv.length > 3){
        var search_window = window.open("main.php?psearch="+sv, "iframe_a");
        parent.focus();
        }
    else {
        document.cookie = "psearch=";"path=/";
        var search_window = window.open("main.php?psearch=", "iframe_a");
        parent.focus();
    }

}
</script>
```